# php - use class methods in another class using global

Tags: php, class

I have 2 classes

```
app/Classes/
    |
    |____ Helper/
    |        |
    |        |____ Helper.php   <- contain Helper Class
    |
    |____ User/
             |
             |____ User.php   <- contain User Class
```

And I have added the classes files to the autoloader dependencies using psr-4. so I can namespace them `composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Classes\\": "app/Classes"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "vlucas/valitron": "1.3.*",
        "ezimuel/php-secure-session": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

After I have dumped the `composer.phar` file from the terminal.
In my `bootstrap.php` I added the autoloader dependencies

```
//bootstrap.php
require_once APP_ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$helper = new Helper();
$user = new User();
```

and now in my `User` class I need the `helper` class

```
namespace Classes\User;

Class User
{
    public function onlyAuthenticated()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

            global $helper;

            $helper->redirect('/index.php');
        }
    }
}
```

All code is working but is it safe to use `global $helper;` inside the `User` class? Is it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `$helper` as global when you initialize it to access it later with the global keyword.

```
//bootstrap.php
...
global $helper;
$helper = new Helper();
```

That said, you are likely better off not doing it this way, at least for something that does what I suspect your `Helper` class does.

You can declare static functions in `Helper` that can be used anywhere without global variables.  Something like:

```
class Helper{ //just some dummy code for demonstration purposes.
    public static function redirect($url){
        header("Location: " $url);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Helper::redirect('/index.php');
```

Note, that is less verbose and in my opinion more clear.  It also has the advantage of not requiring global variables.

Comment: yaa that has worked  all i did is 
`use Classes\Helper\Helper;`
and 
`Helper::redirect('/index.php');`